# A question on IR cancellation calculation in Peskin & Schroeder

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, singularities

In Peskin and Schroeder *Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* book, above equation 6.64 on pg. 200, it was said that "to gain better understanding, of the divergence, let us evaluate the coefficient of the log in the limit of $-q^2\rightarrow\infty$." Why does he want to take $-q^2$ to infinity rather than $0$ to extract the divergence? I thought the form factor $F_1(q^2)$ contains an infrared divergence at $q^2=0$.

Comment: The IR divergence is regulated by the photon mass $\mu$, not by $q^2$. So they are looking for divergences in the $\mu \to 0$ limit. The $q^2 \to \infty$ limit is taken just to understand the structure of the divergence in a particular regime. Of course, the full answer requires the cancellation to occur for all $q^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The photon which generates the divergence has momentum $p-k$ which can be seen at the beginning of section 6.3 in P&S. The fact that you take $-q^{2}\rightarrow\infty$ doesn't affect the possibility of a soft photon appearing. When $-q^{2}\ll1$ you can only have soft photons while in the case of $-q^{2}\rightarrow\infty$ you can get several soft photon and/or hard photons. This is due to the conservation of 4-momentum.